# How to convert accented characters in an email

Tags: text-processing, email, conversion

I want to send an email with the body ($BODY) containing accented characters like é, à, ô...

`echo "$TO" | mail -s $SUBJECT $BODY`

But the result shows unreadable characters.

I tried to correct all this with the `recode` command:

`recode -v -f UTF-8...latin-4 $BODY`

and then I tried the `iconv` command

`iconv -f UTF8 -t ISO885915 $BODY > $BODY1`

But I'm just changing the shape of the unreadable characters. Unable to make accents appear in the email received.

Am I using the correct commands?
Thanks

---

The output of `locale` on my system:

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: You need to specify the charset being used in your email headers (“`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`”); the option to do that depends on your specific `mail` command.

Comment: It works, thanks !

Comment: @RomeoDejent : Could you please detail how "it works" as part as an answer to your own question ?

Comment: Sorry.
I just added the following line: "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" in the header of my email following the sending parameters (To, Cc, Bcc...) and the accents were indeed recognized in the email.
Thus, no conversion command was necessary.